# SQL Server 2008 R2 Replication - Publication creation not working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-replication

I'm trying to set up transactional replication from a SQL Server 2008 R2 (as publisher) to a SQL Server 2000, using the management studio.  However, I can't get past the the creation of the publisher.  I *think* it has something to do with the auto-incrementing ID of one of the tables.

- I have 4 tables that will be replicated (I will create a new DB as subscriber).  One of the tables has an auto-incrementing ID.
- I set the Not For Replication option on 'No' for the ID-column
- When I create the publication, I set 'Automatically manage identity ranges' to Manual.

The creation succeed, however when I open the replication monitor, the agent show an error on the snapshot:

Script failed for Table 'dbo.tbl_With_auto_increment_ID'.

```
Error messages:
Source: Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo
Target Site: System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String] ScriptWithList(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DependencyCollection, Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject[])
Message: Script failed for Table 'dbo.PhraseLog'. 
Stack:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter.ScriptWithList(DependencyCollection depList, SqlSmoObject[] objects)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter.ScriptWithList(SqlSmoObject[] objects)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.TransSmoScriptingManager.GenerateLogBasedArticleSchScript(Scripter scripter, BaseArticleWrapper articleWrapper, Table smoTable)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.TransSmoScriptingManager.GenerateLogBasedArticleScripts(ArticleScriptingBundle articleScriptingBundle)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.TransSmoScriptingManager.GenerateArticleScripts(ArticleScriptingBundle articleScriptingBundle)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.SmoScriptingManager.GenerateObjectScripts(ArticleScriptingBundle articleScriptingBundle)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.SmoScriptingManager.DoScripting()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.SqlServerSnapshotProvider.DoScripting()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.SqlServerSnapshotProvider.GenerateSnapshot()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.SnapshotGenerationAgent.InternalRun()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.AgentCore.Run() (Source: Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Error number: 0)
Get help: http://help/0
Source: Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo
Target Site: Void CheckSupportedType(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptingOptions)
Message: Column LANG_TEXT in object PhraseLog contains type NVarCharMax, which is not supported in the target server version, SQL Server 2000.
Stack:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Column.CheckSupportedType(ScriptingOptions options)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Column.VersionValidate(ScriptingOptions so)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Column.ScriptDdlCreateImpl(StringBuilder sb, ScriptingOptions so)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Column.ScriptDdl(StringCollection queries, ScriptingOptions so)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Table.ScriptTableInternal(ScriptingOptions so, StringBuilder sb, ColumnCollection columns, IndexCollection indexes)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Table.GetTableCreationScript(ScriptingOptions so, StringBuilder sb)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Table.ScriptCreate(StringCollection queries, ScriptingOptions so)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.ScriptCreateInternal(StringCollection query, ScriptingOptions so)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter.ScriptWithListWorker(DependencyCollection depList, SqlSmoObject[] objects)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter.ScriptWithList(DependencyCollection depList, SqlSmoObject[] objects) (Source: Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Error number: 0)
Get help: http://help/0
```

I tried to set the Not For Replication option to both Yes / No, but this doesn't seem to influence the outcome, whether 'Automatically manage identity ranges' is on manual or automatic.

If I set 'Automatically manage identity ranges' to automatic, the publication creation fails (on Ádding article 4 of 4'):

```
===================================

SQL Server Management Studio could not create article 'PhraseLog'. (New Publication Wizard)

===================================

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.ReplicationObject.ExecCommand(String commandIn)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Article.CommonArticleCreate()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Article.Create()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.CreatePublicationWizard.AddArticles(Publication pub, StringBuilder strScriptText, IProgress progress)

===================================

Automatic identity range support is useful only for publications that allow updating subscribers.
Changed database context to 'PhraseLIB'. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

------------------------------
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.2550&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=21231&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
Server Name: zwbe-sql-08
Error Number: 21231
Severity: 16
State: 1
Procedure: sp_MSrepl_addarticle
Line Number: 2243


------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.ExecuteTSql(ExecuteTSqlAction action, Object execObject, DataSet fillDataSet, Boolean catchException)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)
```

I am completely new to replication, and as far as I can tell (after reading some websites) is that 'Automatically manage identity ranges' and 'Not For Replication' are the only options that need to be set for an auto-increment table.  So please tell me what I'm doing wrong here,

Thanks guys n gals,

J.

Comment: The message from replication monitor appears to be saying that it's running into a problem applying the schema script at the subscriber. If you run that script by hand (located in the snapshot folder at the distributor), what happens?

Comment: I never got to the part to create a subscriber.  Those errors are shown when trying to create the publisher.

Comment: Fair enough. In that case, try creating a script from the add publication wizard and running that. What error do you get then?

Comment: @getshirty , please do not just edit tags if there should be done more on a question [Retag is too minor edit?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270158/retag-is-too-minor-edit)